# Xades4j verification enveloped signature

Tags: java, xml, verification, xades4j

I have problem to verify enveloped xml signed with xades4j
error I get is "The Reference for URI #data has no XMLSignatureInput"
where "#data" is uri for my signed xml
verification pass on c# validation

this is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Envelope xmlns="urn:Zahtev"><root Id="data"><Identifikacija><IDZahteva>D1CC353F-6F04-47A4-B900-31944E2A1D53</IDZahteva></Identifikacija></root><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Potpis_RA_Agenta">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#data">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>IWMyfvcgZm3ElP6TfWtqTtGjEos=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#SignedPropertiesId" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>WBLe3LJ12+hQ3OyTClnQcK2crF0=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="Vrednost_za_Potpis_RA_Agenta">
...
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
..
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
<ds:KeyValue>
<ds:RSAKeyValue>
<ds:Modulus>
....
</ds:Modulus>
<ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
</ds:RSAKeyValue>
</ds:KeyValue>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object Id="XadesObject">.....</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature></Envelope>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Santuario (used by xades4j) does not use the "Id" attribute as the XML Id out of the box. You have to set it explicitly. This behavior was introduced on [Santuario's version 1.5](http://santuario.apache.org/java150releasenotes.html). Check this [xades4j tests file](https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/xades4j/utils/SignatureServicesTestBase.java). The [DOMHelper class](https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/xades4j/utils/DOMHelper.java) has helper methods to define XML Ids.

As a side note: that signature is not an enveloped signature, since it is not "inside" the signed element. It is a detached signature. The enveloped signature transform is not needed.